# crontab job log message shows a error status 0x004b from mta#012

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, cron

The `crontab` job log message shows a error status 0x004b from mta#012 when I try to check my crontab job.

```
# grep CRON /var/log/syslog
[...]
```

I get this log:

```
Nov 26 08:00:01 stiitsrv9 CRON[26109]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/sbin/backup-sti-epfl-ch)
Nov 26 08:01:02 stiitsrv9 CRON[26108]: (root) MAIL (mailed 13311563 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
[...]
```

The `crontab` job does not work.

What is this message means and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default cron sends an email with the output of the command executed in cron. If you don't specify a `MAILTO=myself@example.com` it sends to the user under which the cronjob was scheduled.

Cron will use whatever mailserver binary is defined as _PATH_SENDMAIL in /usr/include/paths.h . This is usually sendmail or postfix. Most distributions have a mailserver installed but it might not be configured correctly. Other distros do not have a default mailserver installed (looking at you Ubuntu).

In your case your MTA (Mail Transfer Agent) returns an exit code of 0x004b which is 75 in hexadecimal. This probably means you have a mailserver installed but not configured.

As for solutions:

- configure your MTA so it can send mail. The most basic solution will end up with mails in /var/mail on your server
- redirect output to a file: /example/coolscript.sh >> /var/log/cool.log 2>&1
- if you don't care about the output and just want to get rid of spam in your logs: /example/script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
- if you want the output in syslog:  /example/coolscript.sh 2>&1 | logger -t coolexampletag

Comment: thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: If I write `/example/coolscript.log` instead of `/example/coolscript.sh` by mistake log will be empty and problem won't be solved.